# How to get customer email with Stripe webhook / endpoint

Tags: php, json, stripe-payments, endpoint

Trying to get a customer email using Stripe endpoint  / webhook. The email address isn't showing.

This is what I've got so far:

```
 <?php

 require_once('stripe/init.php');

 \Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey("sk_test_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

 $input = @file_get_contents("php://input");

 $event_json = json_decode($input);

 $customer = $event_json->data->object->email;

 $email_stripe = $customer->email;

 if ($event_json->type == 'charge.failed') {

 }

 if ($event_json->type == 'charge.succeeded') {

 }

 ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

There's no `email` in that object, however there's the [receipt_email](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-receipt_email) which could be used for this. This you'd have to set at the charge time to get it back.

Otherwise there's the [customer](https://stripe.com/docs/api/charges/object#charge_object-customer) where the customer ID is returned. That you can use to make an additional call to [get all the customer's details](https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/retrieve)